# Access query IIF statement to SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, iif

**Problem:** I am trying to get the below code to work in SQL Server.

I wrote the code originally in an MS Access query, but now I need to use it in SQL Server. The problem I have is the `IIF` statements doesn't work in SQL Server.

I have tried using a `Case` statement but it ended up bogging up my SQL Server and never loaded any data. Is there any suggestions on how to convert an `IIF` statement to be used in SQL Server? Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

Code written in MS Access query:

```
SELECT 
    Customer.CustomerID, 
    IIf([ExpenseCode].[SysCode] >= '1747', [Amount], 0) AS Trains
FROM   
    Customer 
LEFT JOIN 
    (Expense 
LEFT JOIN 
    ExpenseCode ON Expense.SysCode = ExpenseCode.SysCode) ON Customer.CustomerID = Expense.EntityID;
```

Attempted solution in SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.CustomerID,
    CASE
        WHEN t.SysCode = '1747'
           THEN e.Amount
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Trains
FROM
    ExpenseCode AS t, Expense AS e, Customer AS r
```

Comment: `IIF()` is supported in SQL Server.

Comment: But [`IIF` *does* work in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql); it was introduced in SQL Server 2012. If you're on a version older than that, the `CASE` equivalent would be `CASE WHEN condition THEN truebranch ELSE falsebranch END` -- you've translated `>=` to `=` and `0` to `NULL`, which seems unwarranted.

Comment: And if you *are* on an older version of SQL Server than 2012, then you should probably be looking at upgrade paths. Any versions prior to 2012 are now completely unsupported.

Comment: What error did you actually receive?  Your implementation of CASE looks like future suggestions already.   What do you mean by 'bogging  up' - does it mean query never completed?  Or threw errors?  Or unknown problem even.  Another issue, you've made LEFT JOIN into CROSS JOIN with no key used in the JOIN - so maybe a performance error?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. You already **had** proper `JOIN`s in MS Access - don't *downgrade* to the old crappy "comma-separated tables in `FROM` approach for your new SQL Server code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IIF()` is supported in SQL Server since version 2012. What you would need to change in your MS Access query is the syntax of the join.

Try:

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerID, 
    IIf(ec.SysCode >= 1747, Amount, 0) AS Trains
FROM   
    Customer c
    LEFT JOIN Expense e ON c.CustomerID = e.EntityID
    LEFT JOIN ExpenseCode ec ON e.SysCode = ec.SysCode;
```

I also added table aliases to your query, since they make it more readable (please add the relevant prefix to column `Amount`). Finally, I considered that `SysCode` was a number, so I removed the surrounding quotes around the value for comparison (it it's indeed a string, you can put the quotes back).

If you are running SQL Server < 2012, here is the `CASE` sytanx:

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerID, 
    CASE WHEN ec.SysCode >= 1747 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END AS Trains
FROM   
    Customer c
    LEFT JOIN Expense e ON c.CustomerID = e.EntityID
    LEFT JOIN ExpenseCode ec ON e.SysCode = ec.SysCode;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you mention this, but you seem to amend it.  His JOIN in SQL is in fact a CROSS JOIN, with no logic on the JOIN, it joins all to all in 3 tables

Comment: @Cato: OP is looking to migrate their query from MS Access to SQL Server. Obviously their attempt using implicit cross joins was not the correct approach...

Comment: I think that's true, I was just pointing it out to him, I think it's the actual problem he has got.

Comment: Hi GMB, I appreciate your feedback. I am using SQL Server 2017 but maybe I mis-researched. I kept getting errors and all I found was it wasn't supported. I tried what you suggested but I get a "incorrect syntax near '>' error. I don't know much of syntax for IIF statements in SQL server, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work in SQL Server.  I would prefer writing it as:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, 
       (CASE WHEN ec.SysCode >= '1747' THEN e.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Trains
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN 
     Expense e
     ON c.CustomerID = e.EntityID LEFT JOIN 
     ExpenseCode ec
     ON e.SysCode = ec.SysCode;
```

This guesses that `Amount` is coming from `Expense`.

The changes:

- SQL Server (and no other databases!) require those awkward parentheses around multiple `JOIN`s.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- `CASE` is the SQL standard for condition expressions, although SQL Server does "retrofit" `IIF()` for MS Access compatibility.
- Qualify all column references!